# Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin^2(t)}{t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Because : $$\mathscr L\left(\frac{f(t)}{t}\right) = \int_s^∞ F(s) ds$$

and $$\mathscr L\left(\sin^2(t)\right) = \frac{2}{s\left(s^2 + 4\right)}$$

then $$∫ \frac{2}{s\left(s^2+4\right)} ds = \frac{1}{2}\ln|s|-\frac{1}{4}\ln|s^2 + 4|$$

What should I do next...?

the answer that textbook gives me is $$\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{s^2 + 4}{s^2}\right)$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [double angle identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae):

\begin{equation}
 \sin^2(t) = \frac{1 - \cos(2t)}{2} 
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
 \mathscr{L}\left[\sin^2(t)\right] = \frac{1}{2s} - \frac{s}{2\left(s^2 + 4\right)}
\end{equation}

We now employ the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of Laplace Transforms:

\begin{equation}
 \mathscr{L}\left[ \frac{f(t)}{t} \right] = \int_{s}^{\infty}\mathscr{L}\left[ f(t) \right]_u\:ds
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{align}
 \mathscr{L}\left[ \frac{\sin^2(t)}{t} \right] &= \int_{s}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{2u} - \frac{u}{2\left(u^2 + 4\right)} \right]\:du = \left[ \frac{1}{2}\ln(u) - \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(u^2 + 4\right)\right]_{s}^{\infty}\\
& = \left[\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{u^2}{u^2 + 4} \right) \right]_{s}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{4}\left[0 - \ln\left(\frac{s^2}{s^2 + 4} \right) \right] = - \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{s^2}{s^2 + 4}\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{s^2 + 4}{s^2}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: If you're looking for other methods, I recommend taking away the 'Answered' status on my comment (many ignore answered questions). 
Up to you of course! Merry xmas!